# Ecto join on multiple conditions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Assuming I have three models:

```
user: has_one wallet
wallet: belongs_to user
transactions: belongs_to wallet
```

I am trying to get all the transactions for a given user. The SQL I can use is the following:

```sql
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   transactions AS t 
   JOIN
      wallets AS w 
      ON w.user_id = 1 
      AND w.id = t.wallet_id
```

Now in Ecto the following works but it does not replicate the query above:

```
wallet = assoc(user, :wallet)
q = from t in Transaction,
join: w in ^wallet,
where: t.wallet_id == w.id,
order_by: [desc: t.id],
select: t
```

I can't find any docs for creating assocs with `AND` cases. I've tried:

```
join: w in (^wallet and assoc(t, :wallet)),
```

but that results in a compile error. The goal would be to write this query on assoc only without manual `id` joins to let the relational abstraction stay within the models.

**EDIT**

following @daniel's suggestion and looking at [dynamic/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2) docs, I managed to build the query with multiple join conditions, by supplying extra conditions in the `on`:

```
id = user.id
q = from t in Transaction,
join: w in assoc(t, :wallet),
on: w.user_id == ^id,
order_by: [desc: t.id],
select: t
```

that snipped produces the following:

```sql
SELECT t0."id" 
  FROM "transactions" AS t0 
  INNER JOIN "wallets" AS w1 
    ON (w1."id" = t0."wallet_id") 
    AND (w1."user_id" = $1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should have made clear what your schemas are, I will assume:

```
schema "transactions" do
  belongs_to :wallet, Wallet
  timestamps()
end

schema "wallet" do
  belongs_to :user, User
  has_many :transactions, Transaction
  timestamps()
end

schema "user" do
  has_one :wallet, Wallet
  timestamps()
end
```

Your query should look the following:

```
def user_transactions_query(id) do
  from tr in Transaction,
    join: wallet in assoc(tr, :wallet),
    join: user in assoc(wallet, :user),
    where: user.id == ^id
end
```

Comment: is it possible to change `where: user.id == ^id` this line with an `assoc` as well, assuming I have the `user` struct available?

Comment: sure, this syntax is the same as making a join

Comment: Although this does solve the problem, it generates an even more complex query than the original one I posted, and does not translate to an `AND` in join.
`SELECT t0."id" FROM "transactions" AS t0 INNER JOIN "wallets" AS w1 ON w1."id" = t0."wallet_id" INNER JOIN "users" AS u2 ON u2."id" = w1."user_id" WHERE (u2."id" = $1)`

Comment: what you are trying to do is a custom type of join. Assocs allow abstraction of join at the cost of flexibility. That type of join cannot be done with assoc and it wouldn't make much sense either.

Comment: yes, I am not fully familiar with ecto yet, I've read parts of the docs, is there any specific parts from docs that relate to this problem that you can recommend?

Comment: the parts you might want to read are: associations, query api, dynamic queries.

Comment: thanks, `dynamic` did the magic, I'll update my question to show the full query, I managed to get this: `SELECT t0."id" FROM "transactions" AS t0 INNER JOIN "wallets" AS w1 ON (w1."id" = t0."wallet_id") AND (w1."user_id" = $1)`